# Paging JSON results with Php & Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I successfully parsed some `json` coming from the `youtube api`, but I can only show 50 results per request (due to the api's limit's), so how would I implement `Javascript` or `Ajax` (what ever you's think is best) into my `php` script to paginate more videos to show up in the results after the viewer gets to the bottom of the list (e.g. a link that says "show 50 more videos")

I'm new to this type of programming, so please help

```
<?php
    $id = urlencode($_GET['id']);
    $url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/$id?alt=jsonc&v=2&start-index=1
&max-results=50";
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($content, true);
    echo "<div id=\"info\"><center><h1><b>{$json['data']['title']}</center></b></h1><br>{$json['data']['description']} there are {$json['data']['totalItems']} uploaded in this playlist.</center><p></div><div class=\"decoration\"></div>";
    echo "<div id=\"center\">";
    echo "<ul>";
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($json['data']['items'] as $items) {
        ++$count;
        echo "<li style=\"width: 300px;min-height: auto;border: none;display: inline-block;margin: 5px;padding:10px;background-color: rgba(17,0,52,0.14);border-radius: 5px;\"><a href=\"video.php?plid={$json['data']['id']}&vidid={$items['video']['id']}\"><font size=\"5\" style=\"font-weight:bold;\">{$items['video']['title']}</font></a><Br \>";
        echo "<a href=\"video.php?plid={$json['data']['id']}&vidid={$items['video']['id']}\"><img style=\"width:300;height:auto;\" src=\"{$items['video']['thumbnail']['hqDefault']}\" title=\"{$items['video']['title']}\" id=\"ytThumb\"></img></a></li>";
    }
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704452/stuck-with-paginating-youtube-api-playlist-results-trying-to-calculate-tha-sum)

By the looks of it you just have to change your `startindex` in the url based on which page the user is on. At the bottom of the page if there were 50 results, just add a link to load more which will call the same url with `startindex` being 1 larger.

Comment: I have had a quick attempt at modifying your code here: http://pastebin.com/shiULh5H
You will need to replace where I wrote thispage.php with what your actual page is called. And I am unsure if the start-index increments by 1 or 50, so try it as 1 and if it only seems to cut off one result each page you go to, then make it 50.

Also note that I have not run this code and it may not work (you will have to debug it)