# YouTube Playlist Pagination

Tags: jquery, json, youtube

I am trying to pull all the videos from a YouTube Playlist with jQuery and display them with some kind of pagination or perhaps next/prev links.

Based on code I found here I have figured out how to pull the first group of videos. You can see it working [here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YYeyy/)

```
    function LoadVids(startindex){
    if (typeof startindex === "undefined" || startindex===null) startindex = 1;
    var maxresults = 25;    

    var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL3B8939169E1256C0?orderby=published&v=2&alt=json&&start-index=' + startindex + '&max-results=' + maxresults;  
    var videoURL= 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
    $.getJSON(playListURL, function(data) {
        var list_data="";
        $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
            var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
            var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
            var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
            var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
            var vid = item.media$group.yt$videoid.$t;
            var url = videoURL + videoID;
            var vidtitle = item.title.$t;
            var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ videoID +"/default.jpg";
            list_data += '<li><a href="'+ url +'" title="'+ feedTitle +'"><img alt="'+ feedTitle+'" src="'+ thumb +'"</a>' + ' - ' + vidtitle + '</li>';
        });
        $(list_data).appendTo(".cont"); 
    });
    }


    //
    $( document ).ready(function() {
     LoadVids(1); // call on load more click
    });
```

After that I'm stuck. I know that you can pull the next and previous links from the feed and you can also get the max number of videos and maybe use that to generate the pagination, I'm just not sure what to do with them. I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704452/stuck-with-paginating-youtube-api-playlist-results-trying-to-calculate-tha-sum), which uses php to do something similar; but I would like to do this with Jquery if it's possible. I'm rather new to jQuery and Json which is probably why I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Are you using the v1 YouTube API? 'Cause it's up to version 3 now.

Comment: I believe this would be for v2, I've only just started learning about v3, would this be easier in v3?